# FieldError: Unknown field(s) (received_time) specified for Event. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class EventAdmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have the following model

```
class Event(models.Model):
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    received_time = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
```

in admin:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['product_type', 'received_time']
```

I get the following error when trying to edit an event (clicking on an individual event in the admin):

```
FieldError at /admin/events/event/20/
Unknown field(s) (received_time) specified for Event. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class EventAdmin.
```

I do see that `editable=False` but I still want it to at least be *visible*, even it it isn't editable. Is there a way to fix this error and edit these items in admin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to keep it in readonly_fields

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['product_type',]
    readonly_fields=('received_time',)
```

Comment: This also works for model methods, to show them in the admin as if they are fields, e.g. the [baby_boomer_status()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#model-methods)  example from the Django docs